# clustering time series with different sized time series

Tags: python, time-series, clustering, dynamic-time-warping

I have read [this article](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-apply-k-means-clustering-to-time-series-data-28d04a8f7da3) on towardsdatascience and they teach how to cluster time series using the DTW distance and the TimeSeriesKMeans from the tslearn.clustering library.
I also read the [official documentation](https://tslearn.readthedocs.io/en/stable/gen_modules/clustering/tslearn.clustering.TimeSeriesKMeans.html) and I found a note.

> **Notes**
>
> If metric is set to “euclidean”, the algorithm expects a dataset of
> equal-sized time series.

This suggest me that for other metrics (like dtw for example) the method works with different sized time series.

I'm currently working on time-series data and I want to check if I can get some interesting information about my data using this method.

This is how I constructed my curves. I have a dataframe called "relevant_figures" that it contains the relevant information in order to construct the curves. Then I proceed as follows:

```
X = []

for _,row in relevant_figures.iterrows():
    input_time = row['InputTime']
    output_time = row['OutputTime']

    ts = weights_df.loc[input_time : output_time]['weight'].copy()
    X.append(ts)
```

When I try the method

```
TimeSeriesKMeans(n_clusters=3, metric="dtw").fit(X)
```

It throws a **ValueError**

> Name: peso, Length: 120, dtype: float64]. Reshape your data either
> using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or
> array.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.

However I can't reshape in order to construct an array because every ts has different lengths. So reshaping does not work. What should I do? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the [to_time_series_dataset](https://tslearn.readthedocs.io/en/stable/gen_modules/utils/tslearn.utils.to_time_series_dataset.html) function in the tslearn.utils module. This takes a list of lists as input and returns the data formatted as a numpy array, e.g.:

```
from tslearn.utils import to_time_series_dataset
X = to_time_series_dataset([[1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3], [2, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]])
```

It looks like it pads the shorter time series with `nan`'s to fit them into the array.

Comment: Thanks Lynn, this method works. It looks like what it pads just like just said.